# YAML parsed as linkedHashMap not as JAVABean

Tags: java, yaml, objectmapper

I have a YAML that should be parsed as JAVA POJO object instead its throwing a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to <mytype>`. The YAML is as below :

```
--- 
- 
  count: 1
  indicies: 
    - be-log-2018.09.20
  searchText: someText
  services: 
    - um
    - sa
- 
  count: 2
  searchText: someMoreText
  services: 
    - um2
    - sa2
- 
  count: 2
  searchText: someMoreText
```

My POJO class is :

```
public class MyType {

    private int count;
    private String searchText;
    private String[] services;
    private String[] indicies;
```

and reading the YAML with :

```
ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
mapper.readValue(new File(path), List.class);
```

Ideally I want to have a empty array if no data is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
List<MyType> myTypeList = objectMapper.readValue(new File(path), new TypeReference<List<MyType>>() {});
```

Read more about [TypeReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html)